# Sometimes ImageView Appears Black

Tags: android, imageview

I am using simple ImageView in my application.

as below

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imvTripArrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_roundtrip_white" />
```

the icon i set for this ImageView is of white color.
But sometimes it appear black instead of white.(Only in device Nexus5 api 21)

below is the theme used in my Activity.

```
<style name="NoTitleBarCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item><!-- tool bar text color-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item> <!-- tool bar-->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/black</item> <!-- notification bar-->
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
```

This issue appears in many ImageView in my application.
I search a lot about this issue but did not found any solution. Anyone pls help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use AppCompatImageView instead of ImageView.

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imvTripArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_roundtrip_white"
        app:tint="#fff/>
```

Add "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true" in gradle.

```html
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        .....    
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```